# UnityWebRequest to UnityEngine.ResourceRequest?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am stuck at updating my code for Resource (AssetBundles) Updater/Manager. I use WWW class which is obsolete/deprecated, and with UnityWebRequest I can't understand how to make this code work again:

```
   public IEnumerator LoadByWWWAsync(string url, WWWLoadCallBack callback)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        LoadState loadState = new LoadState();
        while (!www.isDone)
        {
                     
            loadState.UpdateProgress(www);
            callback(loadState, www);

            yield return 0;
        }

        loadState.UpdateProgress(www);
        callback(loadState, www);
    }
```

And it calls:

```
public void UpdateProgress(ResourceRequest resourceRequest)
{
    isDone = resourceRequest.isDone;
    progress = resourceRequest.progress;
}
```

Normally it looks like:
[image]

But with UnityWebRequest it looks like:
[image]

And I did not find any article at their documentation about that case. Also dig whole API for UnityWebRequest and ResourceRequest and did not find anything about how to convert/cast that, as WWW already do. Maybe someone knows the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as the error tells you your method only takes a `ResourceRequest` as parameter not a `UnityWebRequest`.

Other than apparently `WWW` the `UnityWebRequest` does not inherit from `ResourceRequest`.

To change it is simple since there is [UnityWebRequest.downloadProgress](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-downloadProgress.html)

Change it to

```
public void UpdateProgress(UnityWebRequest www)
{
    isDone = www.isDone;
    progress = www.downloadProgress;
}
```

---

Note:

I also don't see where you actually start sending the request so there won't be any progress:

```
www.SendWebRequest();
```

---

Than also you *can* use

```
var www = new UnityWebResquest(URL);
```

but be aware that this is a generic request and you would have to add things like `DownloadHandler`, `UploadHandler` etc yourself as well as define the type (see [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html))

In your case I'ld rather use [UnityWebRequest.Get](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) Which automatically adds required handlers etc. Unity also recommends using it with `using`

```
using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Get(URL)
{
    www.SendWebRequest();
    while(!www.isDone){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also how about exactly download? Do they works same as WWW? or i should to use something like = UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url); ?

Comment: Updated the answer